# SSIS Derived column- replacing mutiple columns into one

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

requirement is 
source table has 30 columns with a total length of 700 bytes.
I need to make the 30 columns into 7 columns 
as
    1st column
    2nd column
    3rd column
    combine 4th column to 27th column as column 4
    28th column as 5th
    29th column as 6th
    30th column as 7th.

I have tried using derived column in ssis. 
in the expression , I have combined all the columns but when replacing I could not replace all the fields.

Is there any other way to do this in SSIS ?

Comment: You could do your source processing in the source SQL statement. If you want further assistance, please clarify your explanation (commas and newlines really help), supply sample data, and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Source type to SQL Command and combine columns using a similar query: *(SQL Server example)*

```
SELECT ISNULL([Column1],'') + ISNULL([Column2],'') + ISNULL([Column3],'') + 
ISNULL([Column4],'') + ISNULL([Column5],'') + ISNULL([Column6],'') + 
ISNULL([Column7],'') AS [FirstColumn] , 
ISNULL([Column8],'') + ISNULL([Column9],'') + .... AS [SecondColumn] ,
 ...

FROM [SourceTable]
```

*Note: i used `ISNULL` function because when concatenating if one value is `NULL` the whole value will be `NULL`, but note that using function may slow down the query execution performance*

Comment: when using select , the concatenated column is not coming in correct format.

Comment: suppose. COL1 is CHAR(20),COL2 is CHAR(4),COL3 is CHAR(10),Col4 is CHAR(15),COL5 is CHAR(15).

Comment: @RamachandraSedimbi try using `CAST(ISNULL([Col1],'') AS VARCHAR(50))`

Comment: SELECT COL1,ISNULL(COL2,' ') + ISNULL(COL3,' ') +ISNULL(COL4,' ')+ ISNULL(COL5,' ') AS COLUMN2 .The OUTPUT second field is getting added but not in correct format.

Comment: So format it in the query.   Why is this a problem?

Comment: @RamachandraSedimbi what do you mean by `not in correct format`, provide your expected format so we can help

Comment: Thanks yahfoufi, Hadi,Alleman ,Nick and everyone  for your help. Able to get the expected result by using concat function in the source OLE DB query in SSIS and then using a UNION ALL transformation.

Comment: @Ramachandra `Concat` works the same as `+` . Whatever, if this post solved your issue you have to accept it. If you find it helpful u can upvote it. And if you solved this issue with your own answer post it and accept it